# android studio version conflict

Tags: android, android-studio, version, conflict

How to resolve this error?

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6auxw.jpg)

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Comment: change your google play services version to 9.0.0 like it says

Comment: The error message is literally also the answer. . . . . . . . . . . .

Answer (score 0):

The actual Play Services available are 10.2.0

I strongly recommend to use that on your build.gradle app config:

```
 dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before in my project I ran into the same issue. I resolved my issue by using the following build.gradle module:app configuration:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}
```

It is strongly recommended to selectively use play-services to minimize the .APK size of the app. For instance:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
}
```

Goodluck!